# GWT Debugger loses control

Tags: debugging, gwt, remote-debugging

I managed to link GWT debugger to a remote application, but I think there is something wrong in my configuration.

In the arguments I specified the -startupUrl and the debugging only works with this URL.
As soon as I move to another page (of the same application), the module is unloaded and I am no more in "dbugging" mode.
To debug the different pages of the application I have to change the -startupUrl and restart GWT Development Mode, but this disrupt the normal flow.

Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'move to another area'? And how does the startup url look and the url after you 'moved to another area'?

Comment: by "another area" I mean a different page. If for example my startupUrl is http://ext_host:1234/appName/page1.html, I am able to debug this page. If this page points to another one, in the following page I won't be able to debug.
When I am in the first page the URL is something like http://ext_host:1234/appName/page1.html?gwt.codesrv=172.25.1.12:9997 but for the following it will be http://ext_host:1234/appName/page2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *debug* your app, it needs to run in DevMode (code runs as Java in the JVM, and communicates with the browser through the plugin you installed there).

To trigger DevMode in the browser, the URL needs to contain `gwt.codesvr` in the query string with the value being the host and port the DevMode app is listening on.

`-startupUrl` passed to DevMode only makes it easier to get the URLs right, as DevMode will then append the appropriate `gwt.codesvr` to the URL and you can just copy/paste the resulting URL to your browser (or ask DevMode to directly open that URL in your browser).

If you have several HTML host pages and move between them, then for a seamless experience you have to propagate the *gwt.codesvr* part of the URL to the other page.

See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideDevMode for more info about DevMode (it unfortunately omits the bit about how DevMode is triggered by the presence of `gwt.codesvr` in the URL)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that navigating the application the gwt.codesrv get lost. But how can I propagate it without modifying the code?

Comment: You can't propagate it automatically _without_ changing your code. It's rather easy though with `!GWT.isScript()` and `Window.Location.getParameter("gwt.codesvr")`, and possibly `Window.Location.createUrlBuilder()`. (note: `gwt.codesvr` is not the only parameter to look for actually; `gwt.codesvr.myModule` can be used to if you use the `xsiframe` linker, `myModule` of course being the name of your module). You'll find sample code on StackOverflow or the GWT Google Group.